# User Identity Identity Name is Empty from HttpContext

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Basic MVC Tempate Project VS 2013 and MVC 4.

Controller has the following method:

```cs
public string getuserid()
{
    return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
}
```

getuserid returns empty always..

Comment: Assuming the site is hosted on IIS, is Windows Authentication enabled on the site?

Comment: What kind of Membership are you using?

Comment: this is on localhost

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to bet that your application is configured for Anonymous authentication.  You could try using Windows authentication in order to see the identity.